# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object, constructor

My class is

```
class LineAnalyzer

attr_reader :highest_wf_words,:highest_wf_count,:content,:line_number
def initialize(content ="",line_number)
@content = content
@line_number = line_number
end

def calculate_word_frequency
end
end
```

When I make object of class like this

l = LineAnalyzer.new("", 2)

l.calculate_word_frequency

It gives me this error.HOw to avoid this?

Comment: You have to give us more code because when I run your example, I get no error: `#<LineAnalyzer:0x007fd1b981cf08 @content="", @line_number=2>`

Comment: I update my question

Comment: I get nil when I execute this code (which is what I would expect from a method with no code).  What error are you seeing?

Comment: Yes when I call its method l.calculate_word_frequency it gives undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) because its nil .